# AJAX file upload with progress bar and complex form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building an photographer portal with full administration, and I have some issues with creating progress bar for images upload.
I know how to create a progress bar for simple files upload, but in this case the form and process is complexe and nothing I try works.
The files get uploaded, but there's no progress bar.

In my PHP file I'm processing the images like this

```
// imagine initiala
$pictOrig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($tmpName);
$photoX = ImagesX($pictOrig);
$photoY = ImagesY($pictOrig);

// imagini download
$fileFold = '../images/download/';
$pictWidth = $downloadWidth;
$pictHeight = $downloadHeight;
$pictFin = ImageCreateTrueColor($pictWidth, $pictHeight);
ImageCopyResampled($pictFin, $pictOrig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $pictWidth+1, $pictHeight+1, $photoX, $photoY);
ImageJPEG($pictFin,$fileFold.$newName);

// imagini preview
$fileFold = '../images/preview/';
$pictWidth = $previewWidth;
$pictHeight = $previewHeight;
$pictFin = ImageCreateTrueColor($pictWidth, $pictHeight);
ImageCopyResampled($pictFin, $pictOrig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $pictWidth+1, $pictHeight+1, $photoX, $photoY);
ImageJPEG($pictFin,$fileFold.$newName);

// imagini small
$fileFold = '../images/small/';
$pictWidth = $smallWidth;
$pictHeight = $smallHeight;
$pictFin = ImageCreateTrueColor($pictWidth, $pictHeight);
ImageCopyResampled($pictFin, $pictOrig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $pictWidth+1, $pictHeight+1, $photoX, $photoY);
ImageJPEG($pictFin,$fileFold.$newName);
ImageDestroy($pictFin);
ImageDestroy($pictOrig);
```

But, I also have some query's inserting data into a database, so it's not just a file upload form.

Like I said, everything it's working, but there is no progress bar.
This is my AJAX submit,

```
e.preventDefault(e);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: './ajax/process.php',
    data: new FormData(this),
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.msg === 'OK-reload'){
            location.reload();
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

I've tried to insert some xhr functions, but with on luck. If somebody could help me it will be great, but keep in mind the PHP processing which is not only files.

Answer (score 0):

Call/close progressbar function inside your ajax call.

```
e.preventDefault(e);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: './ajax/process.php',
    data: new FormData(this),
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    startprogressbar(); // Display you progressbar container here
    success: function(data) {
    closeprogressbar(); // hide your progressbar container here
    if(data.msg === 'OK-reload'){

        location.reload();
    }
 },
   error: function(data){
      alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried that, but the xhr is not giving me anything. Tried that:

xhr: function () {
                    myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if (myXhr.upload) {
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false);
                    }
                    return myXhr;
                },